# Bringing a DF into a new scheme using merge and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF with many entries. An extract of the DF is shown below.

```
DF_OLD =
...
sID   tID   NER      token           Prediction
274   79    U-Peop   khrushchev      Live_In-ARG2+B
274   79    O        's              Live_IN-ARG2+L
807   53    U-Loc    louisiana       Live_IN-ARG2+U
807   56    B-Peop   earl            Live_IN-ARG1+B
807   57    L-Peop   long            Live_IN-ARG1+L
807   13    B-Peop   dwight          Live_IN-ARG1+B
807   13    I-Peop   d.              Live_IN-ARG1+I
807   13    L-Peop   eisenhower      Live_IN-ARG1+L
...
```

The column `sID` separates the different sentences. The column `Prediction` shows the results of a machine learning classifier. These can be quite nonsensical. My goal is to group all predicted Labels in a scheme such as the following:

```
DF_Expected =
...
sID   entity1              tID1    entity2           tID2   Relation
274   NaN                  NaN     khrushchev 's     79     Live_In 
807   earl long            56 57   louisiana         53     Live_In
807   dwight d. eisenhower 13      louisiana         53     Live_In
...
```

The "-ARGX-" part shows the position of the entities in the table while the part before the first "-" shows the relation. If one of the argument parts is missing, the respective cells should be empty.

Here is what I tried:

```
DF["Live_In_Predict_Split"] = DF["Prediction"].str.split("+").str[0]
DF["token2"] = DF["token"]
DF["tokenID2"] = DF["tokenID"]
DF["Live_In_Predict2"] = DF["Live_In_Predict"]
data_tokeni_map =   DF.groupby(["Live_In_Predict_Split","sentenceID"],as_index=True, sort=False).agg(" ".join).reset_index()
s = data_tokeni_map.loc[:,['sentenceID','token2',"tokenID2","Live_In_Predict2"]].merge(data_tokeni_map.loc[:,['sentenceID','token',"tokenID","Live_In_Predict"]],on='sentenceID')                      
s = s.loc[s.token2!=s.token].drop_duplicates()
```

I'm missing some sort of Counter to separate between the different "-ARGX-" and some sort of GroupBy function (GroupingBy tokenID is not smart as it will yield in wrong results). Therefore my new DF is wrong:

```
DF_EDITED =
...
sID   entity1                         tID1      entity2                     tID2   ...
807   dwight d eisenhower earl long  13 56 57   louisiana                    53   
807   louisiana                      13 56 57  dwight d eisenhower earl long 53
```

EDIT:

Changed my code a bit. Now all useless Predictions are removed but all similar Predictions are grouped together. I need some sort of data preprocessing algorithm to match the data in a form like this, meaning I need to count all Predictions for each `sID` and order them.

```
DF_OLD_Edit =
...
sID   tID   NER      token           Prediction
274   79    U-Peop   khrushchev      Live_In-ARG2+B_1
274   79    O        's              Live_IN-ARG2+L_1
807   53    U-Loc    louisiana       Live_IN-ARG2+U_1
807   56    B-Peop   earl            Live_IN-ARG1+B_1
807   57    L-Peop   long            Live_IN-ARG1+L_1
807   13    B-Peop   dwight          Live_IN-ARG1+B_2
807   13    I-Peop   d.              Live_IN-ARG1+I_2
807   13    L-Peop   eisenhower      Live_IN-ARG1+L_2
...
```

Comment: I acknowledge the effort you made to write your question, but I don't catch why Earl Long should be associated to Louisiana...

Comment: BILOU tagging scheme (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116446/what-do-the-bilou-tags-mean-in-named-entity-recognition) "Earl Long" is the first argument in the relation while "Lousiana" is the second argument. Imagine it this way ("Earl Long Lives_In Louisiana").

Comment: But how would you know to group tID1 56 and 57 together, while for every other one it's based on only a single tID1 value?

Comment: Earl = ARG1-B, Long = ARG1-L => Earl Long. The tID is completely irrelevant in this case. Grouping By tID is also not correct. The first GroupBy should be by ARGX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

`df`

```
   sID  tID     NER       token        Prediction
0  274   79  U-Peop  khrushchev  Live_IN-ARG2+B_1
1  274   79       O          's  Live_IN-ARG2+L_1
2  807   53   U-Loc   louisiana  Live_IN-ARG2+U_1
3  807   56  B-Peop        earl  Live_IN-ARG1+B_1
4  807   57  L-Peop        long  Live_IN-ARG1+L_1
5  807   13  B-Peop      dwight  Live_IN-ARG1+B_2
6  807   13  I-Peop          d.  Live_IN-ARG1+I_2
7  807   13  L-Peop  eisenhower  Live_IN-ARG1+L_2
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import typing

# setting up some columns for groupby
df['arg'] = df.Prediction.apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[1].split("-")[1].split("+")[0])
df['Relation'] = df.Prediction.apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[0])
df['ingroup_id'] = df.Prediction.apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[-1])

# groupby and collect relevant tID and token
df1 = df.groupby(['sID', 'arg', 'ingroup_id']).tID.apply(list)
df2 = df.groupby(['sID', 'arg', 'ingroup_id']).token.apply(list)
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
df3.tID = df3.tID.apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))

# setting up columns that we finally use
df3.loc[df3.arg == 'ARG1', 'tID1'] = df3.tID
df3.loc[df3.arg == 'ARG2', 'tID2'] = df3.tID
df3.loc[df3.arg == 'ARG1', 'entity1'] = df3.token
df3.loc[df3.arg == 'ARG2', 'entity2'] = df3.token

# sort values and then ffill/bfill within the group
df3 = df3.sort_values(['sID', 'arg']).reset_index(drop=True)
df3.tID1 = df3.groupby(['sID']).tID1.ffill()
df3.entity1 = df3.groupby(['sID']).entity1.ffill()
df3.tID2 = df3.groupby(['sID']).tID2.bfill()
df3.entity2 = df3.groupby(['sID']).entity2.bfill()
df3 = df3[['sID', 'entity1', 'tID1', 'entity2', 'tID2']].set_index('sID')

# converting lists in cells into strings (may be someone can make this as a one liner)
df3.entity1 = df3.entity1.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x) if isinstance(x, typing.List) else np.nan)
df3.entity2 = df3.entity2.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x) if isinstance(x, typing.List) else np.nan)
df3.tID1 = df3.tID1.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(str(y) for y in x) if isinstance(x, typing.List) else np.nan)
df3.tID2 = df3.tID2.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(str(y) for y in x) if isinstance(x, typing.List) else np.nan)
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates().reset_index()

df3 = df3.merge(df[['sID', 'Relation']].drop_duplicates(), on='sID', how='left')
```

Output:

```
   sID               entity1   tID1        entity2 tID2 Relation
0  274                   NaN    NaN  khrushchev 's   79  Live_IN
1  807             earl long  56 57      louisiana   53  Live_IN
2  807  dwight d. eisenhower     13      louisiana   53  Live_IN
```

Code is lengthy due to lack of my skill, but basically what it does is `groupby` and `merge` as you suggested in the title. Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use a mixture of functions and DF operations. Those are not efficient at all but it does the trick.

```
def combine(some_list):
current_group = 0 
g_size = 0 
for elem in some_list:
    g_size += 1
    if elem.endswith('U'): 
        if g_size > 1:  
            g_size = 1 
            current_group += 1 
    yield '{}{}'.format(current_group, elem)
    if elem.endswith(('L', 'U')):
        g_size = 0
        current_group += 1

def splitter(DF):
return re.findall('^\d[\d]?[\d]?', DF)  

# Not very efficient
DF["entity2"] = DF["entity"]    
DF["tID2"] = DF["tID"]
DF["Prediction2"] = DF["Prediction"]
DF["Pred_Group"] = list(combine(DF["Prediction"].tolist()))
DF["Jojo"] = DF["Pred_Group"].apply(splitter)
DF["Jojo"] = DF["Jojo"].astype(str).apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))
dmap = DF.groupby(["Jojo","sID"],as_index=True, sort=False).agg(" ".join).reset_index()
s = dmap.loc[:,['sID','entity2',"tID2","Prediction2"]].merge(dmap.loc[:,['sID','entity',"tID","Prediction"]],on='sID')                                             
s = s.loc[s.entity2!=s.entity].drop_duplicates()    
s = s[s["Prediction"].str.contains(r"-ARG2+")]
DF= s[s["Prediction2"].str.contains(r"-ARG1+")]
```