# How to merge multiword NER tags?

Tags: python-3.x, named-entity-recognition, nlp, allennlp

I am using allennlp for NER tagging currently.

Code:

```
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
predictor = Predictor.from_path("...path to model...")
sentence = "Top Gun was inspired by a newspaper article."
result = predictor.predict(sentence)
lang = {}
for word, tag in zip(result["words"], result["tags"]):
  if tag != "O":
    lang[word] = tag
```

Are there any parsers which could merge the output below so that it returns "Top Gun" and tag "WORK_OF_ART" ?

```
{'Top': 'B-WORK_OF_ART', 'Gun': 'L-WORK_OF_ART'}
```

Comment: I given the solution in below Please check  and let me  know 
 Merging Multiword NER Tags using convert results

Answer (score 0):

You can change the model path and try with yours

```
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
predictor = Predictor.from_path("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/ner-model-2018.12.18.tar.gz") # change model path
sentence = "Did Uriah honestly think he could beat The Legend of Zelda in under three hours?"
result = predictor.predict(sentence)

lang = {}

completeWord = ""

for word, tag in zip(result["words"], result["tags"]):
    if(tag.startswith("B")):
        completeWord = completeWord + " " +word
        completeWord = completeWord + " " +word
    elif(tag.startswith("L")):
        completeWord = completeWord + " " +word
        lang[completeWord] = tag.split("-")[1]
        completeWord = ""
    else:
        lang[word] = tag

print(lang)

>>>{' The Legend of Zelda': 'MISC',
 '?': 'O',
 'Did': 'O',
 'Uriah': 'U-PER',
 'beat': 'O',
 'could': 'O',
 'he': 'O',
 'honestly': 'O',
 'hours': 'O',
 'in': 'O',
 'think': 'O',
 'three': 'O',
 'under': 'O'}
```

Please mark it as accepted if useful.

Answer (score 0):

1. This repository contains the all AllenNLP modules download path . you can download what ever you need.
   Click [here](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-demo/blob/55b05b36bcd1dd234011760e1597e2410b4a6f09/models.json)!
2. Download the AllenNLP NER Pretrained model from the below path
   Click [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/bert-base-srl-2020.09.03.tar.gz)!
3. install ALLENNLP and allennlp-models

   pip install allennlp

   pip install allennlp-models
4. Importing required AllenNlp modules

   import allennlp

   from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
5. predictor = Predictor.from_path("https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/bert-base-srl-2020.09.03.tar.gz")
6. Predict function calls AllenNLP’s  Predictor.predict function which takes a passage of text to analyse and classify named entities from unstructured text into pre-defined categories (words, tags, mask and logits). Such as a person’s name, location, landmark, etc. As a library (Pythoncode)
7. BILOU Method/Schema (I hope AllenNLP using BILOU schema)

   ```
   | ------|--------------------------------------|
   | BEGIN | The first token of a final entity    |
   | ------|--------------------------------------| 
   | IN    | An inner token of a final entity     |
   | ------|--------------------------------------|
   | LAST  | The final token of a final entity    |
   | ------|--------------------------------------| 
   | Unit  | A single-token entity                |
   | ------|--------------------------------------|
   | Out   | A non-entity token entity            |
   | ------|--------------------------------------|
   ```

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116446/what-do-the-bilou-tags-mean-in-named-entity-recognition)!

**Input**

Import Required packages

```
    import allennlp
    from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
    predictor = Predictor.from_path("https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/bert-base-srl-2020.09.03.tar.gz")
      

    document = """The U.S. is a country of 50 states covering a vast swath of North America, with Alaska in the northwest and Hawaii extending the nation’s presence into the Pacific Ocean. Major Atlantic Coast cities are New York, a global finance and culture center, and capital Washington, DC. Midwestern metropolis Chicago is known for influential architecture and on the west coast, Los Angeles' Hollywood is famed for filmmaking"""


    ####### Convert Entities ##########
    def convert_results(allen_results):
        ents = set()
        for word, tag in zip(allen_results["words"], allen_results["tags"]):
            if tag != "O":
                ent_position, ent_type = tag.split("-")
                if ent_position == "U":
                    ents.add((word,ent_type))
                else:
                  if ent_position == "B":
                      w = word
                  elif ent_position == "I":
                      w += " " + word
                  elif ent_position == "L":
                      w += " " + word
                  ents.add((w,ent_type))
        return ents
    

    def allennlp_ner(document):
        return convert_results(predictor.predict(sentence=document))

    results = predictor.predict(sentence=document)
    
    [tuple(i) for i in zip(results["words"],results["tags"])]

    ##Output##
    [('The', 'O'),
    ('U.S.', 'U-LOC'),
    ('is', 'O'),
    ('a', 'O'),
    ('country', 'O'),
    ('of', 'O'),
    ('50', 'O'),
    ('states', 'O'),
    ('covering', 'O'),
    ('a', 'O'),
    ('vast', 'O'),
    ('swath', 'O'),
    ('of', 'O'),
    ('North', 'B-LOC'),
    ('America', 'L-LOC'),
    (',', 'O'),
    ('with', 'O'),
    ('Alaska', 'U-LOC'),
    ('in', 'O'),
    ('the', 'O'),
    ('northwest', 'O'),
    ('and', 'O'),
    ('Hawaii', 'U-LOC'),
    ('extending', 'O'),
    ('the', 'O'),
    ('nation', 'O'),
    ('’s', 'O'),
    ('presence', 'O'),
    ('into', 'O'),
    ('the', 'O'),
    ('Pacific', 'B-LOC'),
    ('Ocean', 'L-LOC'),
    ('.', 'O'),
    ('Major', 'B-LOC'),
    ('Atlantic', 'I-LOC'),
    ('Coast', 'L-LOC'),
    ('cities', 'O'),
    ('are', 'O'),
    ('New', 'B-LOC'),
    ('York', 'L-LOC'),
    (',', 'O'),
    ('a', 'O'),
    ('global', 'O'),
    ('finance', 'O'),
    ('and', 'O'),
    ('culture', 'O'),
    ('center', 'O'),
    (',', 'O'),
    ('and', 'O'),
    ('capital', 'O'),
    ('Washington', 'U-LOC'),
    (',', 'O'),
    ('DC', 'U-LOC'),
    ('.', 'O'),
    ('Midwestern', 'U-MISC'),
    ('metropolis', 'O'),
    ('Chicago', 'U-LOC'),
    ('is', 'O'),
    ('known', 'O'),
    ('for', 'O'),
    ('influential', 'O'),
    ('architecture', 'O'),
    ('and', 'O'),
    ('on', 'O'),
    ('the', 'O'),
    ('west', 'O'),
    ('coast', 'O'),
    (',', 'O'),
    ('Los', 'B-LOC'),
    ('Angeles', 'L-LOC'),
    ("'", 'O'),
    ('Hollywood', 'U-LOC'),
    ('is', 'O'),
    ('famed', 'O'),
    ('for', 'O'),
    ('filmmaking', 'O')]

    # Merging Multiword NER Tags using convert_results
    allennlp_ner(document)
    
    # the output print like this

    {('Alaska', 'LOC'),
    ('Chicago', 'LOC'),
    ('DC', 'LOC'),
    ('Hawaii', 'LOC'),
    ('Hollywood', 'LOC'),
    ('Los', 'LOC'),
    ('Los Angeles', 'LOC'),
    ('Major', 'LOC'),
    ('Major Atlantic', 'LOC'),
    ('Major Atlantic Coast', 'LOC'),
    ('Midwestern', 'MISC'),
    ('New', 'LOC'),
    ('New York', 'LOC'),
    ('North', 'LOC'),
    ('North America', 'LOC'),
    ('Pacific', 'LOC'),
    ('Pacific Ocean', 'LOC'),
    ('U.S.', 'LOC'),
    ('Washington', 'LOC')}
```